# Is there a way to reptyr a make process or any process with subprocesses?

Tags: tty, pty, reptyr

Consider the following `Makefile`.

```
all:
    yes
```

If I run `make` and suspend using `Ctrl-Z`, and then start `screen` or `tmux`, followed by an attempt to `reptyr`, I get the following error.

```
$ reptyr 5328
[-] Process 5329 (yes) shares 5328's process group. Unable to attach.
(This most commonly means that 5328 has suprocesses).
Unable to attach to pid 5328: Invalid argument
```

It is certainly true that `make` has subprocesses, but is there a way to `reptyr` anyways, either using this tool or another tool?

Answer (score 11):

`reptyr` version 0.6 introduced `-T` option for "tty-stealing" mode, which works on processes with children.

See https://blog.nelhage.com/2014/08/new-reptyr-feature-tty-stealing/ for more details.